# Microsoft.Web.Administration get sub application

Tags: c#, iis

Say I have this type of config:

- Site 1 (with an AppPool)

  - Virtual Directory
  - Virtual Directory 2
  - Site 2  (with an AppPool)

I'm tring to get the Site 2 informations but the only thing I can get is the path to the folder.

Comment: That's not called sub sites, but applications. Once you know this, you should be able to dig into MWA's relevant classes and properties.

Comment: Thx, I changed the title to reflect your comment.